# Why does the image texture look darker on the mesh than in the UV editor?

Tags: texturing, uv

The texture on the mesh is darker than the image, which is forcing me to change the skin color of the mesh a bit darker. Is there a way to fix this? If not, why is this actually happening?

[image: Screenshot of Fin mesh in UV editing]

Comment: Maybe make sure that the color management is set to Standard, or that the lights are strong enough?

Comment: On the mesh it is shown shaded, reacting to its environment depending on the settings for the surface in the material shader. In the _UV Editor_ it just shows the image, like for example Photoshop would. No shading, lighting, reflections or anything.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you